# NDEF Signature Record Android

Tags: android, nfc, record, signature, ndef

Is there anyway to add a signature record to my NDEF Message in Android?

I am developing a P2P ticketing system (since access to the SE is not available on non rooted devices) for my dissertation and would like to add security to it by adding a Signature Record to the sender's NDEF Message.

The NFC Forum released the Signature Record Type Definition for NDEF Messages in 2010 (http://www.nfc-forum.org/specs/spec_license/document_form/custom_layout?1361543311878) but I can't find anyway to add this to my Message in Android.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got signature record support in this [Eclipse plugin](http://code.google.com/p/nfc-eclipse-plugin/) of mine, and you can create such records programmatically using [this](http://code.google.com/p/ndef-tools-for-android/) Android nfc lib. There is however no end-to-end behind the functionality represented by the record. See [this](http://code.google.com/p/nfcsigning/) site for a starting point, but note that the code was created before the signature record type definition was final.

Comment: Thanks for your help. At least I have something to work on. I only just managed to send text/plain today, this might get complicated :). I'm surprised there is no mention of the signature in the Android Developers site :/.